# Getting user agent for error report form in drupal

Tags: forms

I have created a website error form in drupal8 and want to grab the user agent when they submit the form. As the user click the submit button the user agent should also be saved to the database along with data of all the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. Add a field to the form to store the user agent.
2. Set permissions for the user agent field to be hidden. You can do this in `hook_form_alter` or use something like the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions/) module.
3. In `hook_entity_presave`, save the user agent to the field:

`$user->set('field_text_log_useragent', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`

Comment: I am not able to get it, its not passing the user agent value.

Comment: @manpin I use this approach on my own site so it does work. Check your code carefully for mistakes.

Comment: so I am doing like this
added a field and set the #type = 'hidden'
and tried setting the value of the field 
by hook_entity_presave in form.module 
but unable to do so.

so whats $user here
field_text_log_useragent is filed hidden name, right?

Comment: @manpin You need to load the user account object for $user. For the field, you need to use the actual machine name of whatever you called your field.

Comment: I able to that in a different way, anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: @manpin You should post your own answer to the question then so that others can benefit from your solution.